# JSON: read array from DB

Tags: json, database, swift, xcode6

I need to get the location from the database, it's an array.

I already try a lot of code but every code get me an error like "Could not cast a value of type NSArray to NSDictionary" or something like that.

This is my last try:

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary
var location = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["locations"] as! NSDictionary)["location_name"] as! String
println(customernamedb)
```

This is my response:

> {"status":"1","city_name":"Mumbai","city_id":"3","locations":[{"location_id":"1","location_name":"Andheri"},{"location_id":"2","location_name":"Lower Parel"},{"location_id":"59","location_name":"Lower Parel"},{"location_id":"102","location_name":"Lower Parel"},{"location_id":"144","location_name":"Borivali"},{"location_id":"145","location_name":"Borivali"},{"location_id":"146","location_name":"Borivali"},{"location_id":"147","location_name":"Andheri"}]}

I need to read all `location_name`.

Comment: `((jsonData as NSDictionary)["locations"]` is a NSArray.

Comment: ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["locations"] as! NSArray) ["location_name"] as! String it says : AnyObject is not convertible to String

Comment: When parsing JSON, always remember that anything inside [ ] is an array of somethings and anything inside { } is a dictionary.  An array can contain both arrays and dictionaries and a dictionary can contain both dictionaries and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access an array like it was a dictionary...

Note: instead of stacking everything on the same line, you should break down the statements and use safe unwrapping.

Example:

```
if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject] { // dictionary
    if let locationsArray = jsonData["locations"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] { // array of dictionaries
        for locationDictionary in locationsArray { // we loop in the array of dictionaries
            if let location = locationDictionary["location_name"] as? String { // finally, access the dictionary like you were trying to do
                println(location)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 2.0**

```
do {
    if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let locationsArray = jsonData["locations"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for locationDictionary in locationsArray {
                if let location = locationDictionary["location_name"] as? String {
                    print(location)
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```